# Vue-router & webpack: configure routes using environment variables at build time

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue.js app that is intended to for several deployments.  For one deployment, the url should be `<domian>/`. For other, however, it may need to be `<domain>/tool`. Those routes will be set using an environment variable: `TOOL_ROUTE=/` or `TOOL_ROUTE=/tool`

The problem is, that using vue-router, I need to specify in `main.js` what the tool should expect from the url:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
var Vuex = require('vuex');
var sync = require('vuex-router-sync').sync;
var App = require('./vue/App.vue');
var Content = require('./vue/Content.vue');
var Configurator = require('./vue/components/Configurator.vue');
var store = require('./vue/store/store.js');

var router;

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/tool', component: Content, name: 'home' },
    { path: '/tool/config', component: Configurator, name: 'config' }
  ]
});

sync(store, router);

new Vue({
  router: router,
  store: store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Is there a way to replace `/tool` with the value of an env variable when I compile?

Comment: Do you mean `process.env.TOOL_ROUTE`?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a good way to get this into the js. Relatively new to webpack.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then because that's how you would retrieve the environment variable in your main.js file. Here's documentation on `process.env` https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: If I set `TOOL_ROUTE` in the env and then modify `main.js` to use  `{ path: process.env.TOOL_ROUTE, component: Content, name: 'home'}`, the route defined here is `path: undefined`

Comment: How are you setting `TOOL_ROUTE`?

Comment: `export TOOL_ROUTE=/tool` in the shell prior to building

Answer (score 1):

You have to forward the environment variable during your webpack build. You can do that the same way you set the `NODE_ENV` variable.

```
var route = process.env.TOOL_ROUTE || '/tool'; // default value if the variable isn't set

route = '"' + route + '"'; // encapsulate with "

console.log('Tool route:', route);

module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  TOOL_ROUTE: route // make sure it is exported
}
```

You can now access the value in your code:

```
routes: [
    { path: process.env.TOOL_ROUTE, component: Content, name: 'home' },
    { path: process.env.TOOL_ROUTE + '/config', component: Configurator, name: 'config' }
  ]
```

> Note: for the vue-cli webpack template, do this in `config/prod.env.js`. This will be merged in the `dev` and `test` environments.
>
> Take into account that you will need to build every time the value of the environment variable changes!